# Contextual type of dependent parameter

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get contextual typing for function parameters, when overloading with a union?

```
declare function f(...args: [x: 'a', y: (a: string) => void] | [x: 'b', y: (a: boolean) => void]): void;

// Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)
f('a', x => {});

declare function g(x: 'a', y: (a: string) => void): void;
declare function g(x: 'b', y: (a: boolean) => void): void;

// Ok.
g('a', x => {});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIAoA6E2AcwGcAueAbQA8aByKJgGngE8aCoaKMMLKjIBKeAF4AfPABuOLMAC68AD51G8JgCN2XHn3jacOCCCipx0uQuWia8xQG4AUC4D07+AAVYUALYgGCAwWvRM8Fj+AA4QWGBYGBCc8AAWUBTwFloWnBEYnNEgRAQA7AAM5QBsoi6IBCx69JIyAN4AvqKuLqCQsAgo6Nh48GQEmo0c3PC8-ILCYi02ivbLwK690HBIaJi4+GMTulMGNMam5pZLjsCrN92e8ADyANZELmOT8M3WHV1AA)

Especially after the work for [dependent parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#dependent-parameters-cfa), i thought it would work? Is there an open issue to track this?

Comment: That's surprising. It's clearly picking up the right member from the union, because it complains (correctly) about `f("a", (a: boolean) => {});`...

Comment: If you write out the type, it can see the arguments aren't assignable to the union (no deduction necessary). Contextual typing needs it to understand what possibilities from the union are left over, and in this case (similar to the feature for dependent parameters), only one remains, so it should be able to infer the type of `x`. However, apparently not, so my only guess is that small piece hasn't been added to the puzzle yet, although surprising.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my comment. I was saying that yes, it's surprising, not least because TypeScript has inferred the other parts correctly.